# How to store shiny R settings and load them from a file

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to store and load the settings selected by a user in shiny but have not been able to get it to work. The `dput` and `dget()` functions seem to be working but the UI does not get updated. What am I missing?

```
library(shiny)

outputDir <- "responses"

saveData <- function(inData) {
  # Create a unique file name
  fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s.txt", as.integer(Sys.time()), digest::digest(inData))
  # Write the file to the local system
  dput(inData, file = paste0(outputDir, '/', fileName))
}

# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Slider for the number of bins ----
      sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                  label = "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),

      selectInput("columns", "Select columns to exclude From gather", multiple = T, 
                  choices = c('choice1', 'choice2','choice3')),

      actionButton('submit', "Save inputs"),

      actionButton('load', "Load inputs")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Histogram ----
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")

    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  AllInputs <- reactive({
    reactiveValuesToList(input)
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    saveData(AllInputs())
  })

  observeEvent(input$load,{
    files <- list.files(outputDir, full.names = TRUE)
    inData <- dget(file = files)
    for (i in 1:length(inData)) {
      session$sendInputMessage(names(inData)[i], list(inData[[names(inData)[i]]]))
    }
  })

  # Histogram of the Old Faithful Geyser Data ----
  # with requested number of bins
  # This expression that generates a histogram is wrapped in a call
  # to renderPlot to indicate that:
  #
  # 1. It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically
  #    re-executed when inputs (input$bins) change
  # 2. Its output type is a plot
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: on dget(file =files) you potentially read multiple files. Which settings should be read in this case?

Comment: @Omri374 I would like the user to be able to select the file so maybe using `fileInput` would be a better option but I wasn't sure if `dget` could be paired with that.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. if your `fileInput` is called file1, you can call `dget(input$file1$datapath)`

Comment: @Omri374 yeah, that is definitely a better choice than the way I currently select it but the ‘sessionInputMessage’ call is still not working to load in the settings. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: I tried it myself and it didn't work... not sure how sessionInputMessage works, sorry.

Comment: I think it’s supposed to be the final call made by updateSelectInput etc so supposedly it can be used to update any input value directly